# Conditional creation of file from existing files

Tags: unix, ksh

I have a requirement here:
My shell script will be having multiple files to process and suppose If I am having data file in the following format:

```
H:ASDSA_20110221010224_0018020110221010224ASDFDGDA         QWEERET
11594          1              XXCT5                                             500            1                                         
11594          1              XXCT5                                             500            1              
T:2         

OR 

11594          1              XXCT5                                             500            1                                         
11594          1              XXCT5                                             500            1
```

I need to create a new file out of the above data files based on the following condition:
a. If the data file is having the first line starting with H: and the last line ending with T:, the new file should be(without row starting with H: and T):

1

```
1594          1              XXCT5                                             500            1                                         
1594          1              XXCT5                                             500            1
```

b. If the data file is not having H: and T: in the begining and end of the data file, the new file should be(without row starting with H: and T):

```
11594          1              XXCT5                                             500            1                                         
11594          1              XXCT5                                             500            1
```

Please get back to me with an appropriate solution.

Thanks,
Arun

Answer (score 0):

This may do what you want.

```
sed '1{/^H/d};${/^T/d}' inputfile
```